# Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked never being called from native code

Tags: react-native

In my react-native project, I am getting the following error message:

> Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code

[screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS09i.png)

```js
    const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

    const ProductView = ({ navigation }) => {
        //const getDiv = useSelector((state) => state.reducerDiv.divId)

        const [itemsData, setItemsData] = useState([]);
        const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
        const route = useRoute();
        const id = route.params?.id;
        const item = itemsData?.find((i) => i.id === id);

        useEffect(() => {
            getData();
        }, []);

        const getData = async () => {
            try {
            const response = await axios.post(`url`);
            setItemsData(response.data.data);
            } catch (error) {
            console.warn(error);
            } finally {
            setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            if (item) {
            setCurrentIndex(itemsData.indexOf(item));
            }
        }, [item, id]);

        const handleScroll = (event) => {
            const contentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
            const index = Math.round(contentOffset / SCREEN_WIDTH);
            setCurrentIndex(index);
        };
        // <-----------------------------------horizontal screen--------------------------------------------->
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <View style={styles.body} key={item.id}>
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: item.image ? item.image : null }} style={styles.productImg} resizeMode="contain" />
                </View>
                <View style={{ paddingEnd: 50 }}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", marginTop: 15, justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
                        <Text style={styles.textItem}>Brand name</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{item?.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image source={require("../image/share.png")} style={styles.shareImg} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Image source={require("../image/screenshot.png")} style={styles.shareImg} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
        if (loading) {
            return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <LinearGradient colors={["#7ABF49", "#13A15D"]} start={{ x: 0.99, y: 0 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }} style={styles.linearGradient}>
            <HeaderItem navigation={navigation} />

            <FlatList
                data={itemsData}
                horizontal={true}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                onScroll={handleScroll}
                scrollEventThrottle={160}
                contentOffset={{
                x: currentIndex * SCREEN_WIDTH,
                y: 0,
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                renderItem={renderItem}
            />
            </LinearGradient>
        );
    };
```

Comment: You may want to check useEffect which might be causing infinite loop
useEffect(() => {

    if (item) {
        setCurrentIndex(itemsData.indexOf(item));
    }
}, [item, id]);